# C# WPF - Not able to show text

Tags: c#, wpf

I've followed this guide on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p2K4P9df8g

in the guide these navbuttons are created
`<local:NavButton Navlink="/Pages/Page3.xaml" Margin="3" Padding="6" Icon=" remove for readability "/>`

```
                <Border x:Name="back" CornerRadius="8" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Path x:Name="icon" Height="18" Width="18" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#7b8792" Data="{TemplateBinding Icon}"/>
                </Border>
```

I've already created this in NavButton.cs, but i can't seem to get the text visable, any help would be greatly appriciated.

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(NavButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the text visible, you'll need to add a text element (e.g., a TextBlock) within your NavButton control's XAML template. Here's an example of how you can modify your XAML to include the text:

```
<Style TargetType="local:NavButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:NavButton">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- Add your text here -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    <Border x:Name="back" CornerRadius="8" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Path x:Name="icon" Height="18" Width="18" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#7b8792" Data="{TemplateBinding Icon}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style
```

> 

In this modified template, a TextBlock element is added within the Grid to display the text. The Text property of the TextBlock is bound to the Text property of your NavButton. This way, when you set the Text property in your NavButton control, it will be displayed as text within the button.

Now, when you use your NavButton control and set the Text property, the text should be visible on the button. For example:

```
<local:NavButton Navlink="/Pages/Page3.xaml" Margin="3" Padding="6" Icon="YourIconData" Text="Button Text"/>
```

Make sure to replace "YourIconData" with your actual icon data and "Button Text" with the text you want to display on the button.